# Epsilon-delta proof of continuity at a point

Tags: real-analysis

I would like to make sure my understanding of a simple epsilon-delta proof is sound. The problem:

> Prove, using the definition of continuity at a point, that the following function is continuous on the given domain: *f(x) = ax + b, with   a,  b $\in$ $\Bbb{R}$, on $\Bbb{R}$*.

My work:

Let *c* $\in$ $\Bbb{R}$ and $\varepsilon$ > 0. We need a $\delta$ > 0 such that

$|x -  c| < \delta$ $\implies |f(x) - f(c)| < \varepsilon $.

We start by finding a suitable $\delta$.

$|f(x)-f(c)|<\varepsilon \leftrightarrow |ax + b - (ac + b)| < \varepsilon$, and

$|ax + b - (ac + b)| = |a||x-c|$.

So 
$ |a||x-c|<\varepsilon $
$\quad \quad \ |x-c| < {\varepsilon \over  |a|}$.

Thus, we choose $\delta = {\varepsilon \over |a|}$. Now,
$|x-c|<\delta \leftrightarrow |x-c|< {\varepsilon \over |a|}$
$\qquad \qquad \quad  \ |a||x-c| < \varepsilon$
$\quad \qquad \; \;  |f(x) - f(c)| < \varepsilon$.

If I understand correctly, the proof is complete since I've shown
$|x -  c| < \delta$ $\implies |f(x) - f(c)| < \varepsilon $ for some $\delta$.

But I am uncertain if I made a mistake in my choice of $\delta$ or any other manipulations. Any insights would be appreciated.

Comment: What if $a=0$? You can fix that by taking $\epsilon/(|a|+1)$ instead.

Comment: Your logic is fine (except as noted elsewhere you need to adjust your proof slightly for the case $a=0$).  As a matter of rhetoric I'd explicitly point out that since your choice of $c$ was arbitrary, this proof demonstrates that $f(x)$ is continuous on all of $\Bbb R$, as required.  This is certainly implicit in your reasoning -- as a matter of style I'd simply make it explicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is o.k. in the case $a \ne 0.$ If $a=0$, we have $f(x)=b$ for all $x$, hence

$|f(x)-f(c)= |b-b|=0 < \epsilon$.